# How to get the current Java version available?

Tags: c#, java

How do i get the current Java version available using c#?

I have been able to find a way to get the java version on my PC using C# but I need to be able to compare the installed version with the most current version available.  At the moment I am unable to find an API or web service to get this information.

Hopefully someone here knows the answer to this.

Comment: Use C# to run unix commands.  Echo what version of Java you have.  I don't know how you would know the latest version of Java without hard-coding it.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Are you asking about trying to find the latest Java release from someone (there are lots of different ones) or finding the newest one installed on some maching?

Comment: I am looking to write some code to go out to some api, web service to find out what is the latest version of the code.  Then compare it with what the user has installed.  With that information I will do some other stuff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Latest version available**

You can pull the current version available for download from this page:

http://java.com/en/download/index.jsp

using this selector

```
.jvc0w2 > strong:nth-child(3)
```

A library like [HTML Agility Pack for C#](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) makes this straightforward.

**Version currently installed**

```
RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine;
RegistryKey subKey = rk.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\JavaSoft\\Java Runtime Environment");

string currentVerion = subKey.GetValue("CurrentVersion").ToString();
```

**Caveats**

You will need to reconcile the formats of these two strings for comparison.

If the website I referenced to check the current version changes, you will may need to update your selector.

Comment: Until Oracle changes the structure/css of that page.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar Yep, I called that out at the bottom.  Important caveat.  Thanks for mentioning that as it is easy to forget this dependency.

Comment: First I can't use a third party pack.  Secondly mikeTheLiar is right if I troll the page for the version # when the next version comes out if it isn't the same format I then have to re-code.  But of the people who have answered yours seems to be the closet.  So what I am gathering here is that there isn't a web service or api that allows users to go out and get the Newest Java version available.  There has to be a way considering the java that is installed lets the user know that there is a newer version available.  It might not be available to the public and something I have to work around

Comment: You don't have to use a third party pack at all, it just makes parsing HTML much easier if you have not done a lot of that from scratch.  The second concern is valid, the page may change, but I don't know of a more direct way to consult the Java gods for what version is latest.

Comment: When I go to the link and click "Get Java Version" (or whatever) it tells me I don't have the plugin needed. And I don't have, looking in regedit, a JavaSoft folder in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = "javac";
psi.UseShellExecute = true;
psi.RedirectStandardError = true;

psi.Arguments = "-version";
Process p = Process.Start(psi);
string strOutput = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
```

Then you should parse the string of output. This output normally looks like:

```
javac 1.6.0_27
```

In case you are interested in the Runtime Environment (RE), replace `javac` with `java`

Comment: This fails for me and I have Java 1.7.0_25 installed.  (doesn't find javac or java from command line)

Comment: I currently don't have a machine with `mono` installed. So this is basically code written without executing it myself. Can you specify what fails? You need to import `System.Diagnostics`.

Comment: -1 for not reading the question: WN asks for the latest version available for download, not the currently installed java version!

Comment: If you type "java -version" from the DOS box command line, does it run? If not, there are no versions of java in the path.

Comment: Of course that doesn't mean Java is not installed. But since nobody can know where the java compiler is located (unless performing a hard disk drive search), one should use the fact that Java normally will add itself to the $PATH environment.

Comment: Adding a try/catch block around the line where the process is started can be a lazy check for the presence of javac.

Comment: I have code similar to this already.  This is getting local machine version and I need to get version that can be downloaded if it is newer than what is on the machine.

Comment: I get, System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The Process object must have the UseShellExecute property set to false in order to redirect IO streams.
When I do that (set UseShellExecute to false), I get, "The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: @B.ClayShannon: indeed, it was an error about the shell. But about the file, that depends on the level with which you bind `javac` with the actual compiler. It is better not to do this at compiler level.

Answer (score 1):

Find all the java.exe files and run them as "java -version". The output looks something like this:

```
java version "1.6.0_35"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_35-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.10-b01, mixed mode, sharing)
```

So you can tell the version.

You should also look for the folder structure used by an installed java version.

Comment: Seeings how this is a C# or Java Question and William is looking for code not a command to run

Comment: @MicahArmantrout I don't read the question that way. It doesn't say he is looking for code. I read it that he can find the installed version but needs to know how to find other versions on the machine. Looking for files and running programs and collecting output seems to me as details.

Comment: "At the moment I am unable to find an API or web service to get this information"

Comment: @MicahArmantrout And I explained a way without using either. We may just disagree on this, sir.

Comment: @MicahArmantrout Since you're crossing VM platforms, there's no good way to ask Java questions from .NET. `exec` is the most practical option.

Comment: @chrylis totally agree my only comment that williams is looking for code ... not how to use a command line .... maybe I just read it wrong though

Comment: usually people are looking for code when they post in this form

Comment: What I was looking for is a web service or api to get the newest version available for download.  Not what is currently on my local machine.  I have the code get the local machine version.  I don't have the code to go out to Oracle to get the newest version than can be downloaded.